# Proper javascript Fetch request

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a fetch request from a website, but it's not actually giving me what I need - it seems to just be giving me metadata about the site, and not the actual file I want.

Here's my fetch request:

```
 const url = 'https:///file.txt';
        const options = {
            headers: {
                dataType: 'json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer cdDDerfkorio354kl5lkKKL'
            }
        };

 fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

And then this is what I'm getting:

```
{"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"headers":{"map":{"content-type":"text/plain","x-proxy-cache":"HIT","etag":"\"f-5b6ea3fd2a0ce\"","server":"nginx","date":"Sun, 20 Dec 2020
19:27:15 GMT","content-length":"15","accept-ranges":"bytes","alt-svc":"quic=\":443\"; ma=86400; v=\"43,39\"","host-header":"5d77dd967d63c3104bced1db0cace49c","last-modified":"Sun,
20 Dec 2020 19:21:32 GMT","cache-control":"public, max-age=0"}},"url":"https://mywebsite.com/file.txt","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":15,"offset":0,"b
lobId":"b88a20fa-1d7f-497d-804d-ada1bb213b4c","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":15,"offset":0,"blobId":"b88a20fa-1d7f-497d-804d-ada1bb213b4c","__collector":{}}}}
```

Comment: You need to call `.text()` or `.json()` on `response`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch (when a function or API gives unexpected results, *always* check the docs first)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in two steps:

- First promise fulfills with response object containing only header information and associated stream body.
- In your case, second `.then` will take the response stream, read it to completion and parse body text as JSON.

```js
 fetch(url, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(parsed => console.log(parsed))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This way of handling the response twice lets you to look at headers (for example response status) and decide what you want to do with content body stream.

Comment: This is what worked. I didn't catch it because I was getting an error with it - I didn't know  that JSON objects also needed to have all double quotes. 
So anyone that's having the same problem - parse it to JSON and make sure you're JSON object contains no double quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a JSON response, you can use the `.json()` method on the response to read the response stream and return JSON.

```js
 const url = 'https:///file.txt';
        const options = {
            headers: {
                dataType: 'json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer cdDDerfkorio354kl5lkKKL'
            }
        };

 fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Note that if the result is a string or null, it will throw an exception, even though those are valid JSON.